# How to remove the redundant encoding style for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

I am beginning to use Sublime Text and have fallen in love with it at the first sight.  I really enjoy this powerful editor. I am en editor from China,so I think I only need **UTF-8** and **GBK** encoding option,but each time when I want to save the file with the specified encoding option,there will be a lot of options ,such as

- Western (Windows 1521)
- Western (ISO 8859-1)
- Western (ISO 8859-3)
- ...
- Vietnamese (Windows 1258)

So my question is how do I remove the redundant encoding option for Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this section of `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` and remove all of the encoding that you do not wish to appear in the `Save with Encoding` menu.

```
{
    "caption": "Save with Encoding",
    "children":
    [
    { "caption": "UTF-8", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-8" } },
    { "caption": "UTF-8 with BOM", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-8 with bom" } },
    { "caption": "UTF-16 LE", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-16 le" } },
    { "caption": "UTF-16 LE with BOM", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-16 le with bom" } },
    { "caption": "UTF-16 BE", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-16 be" } },
    { "caption": "UTF-16 BE with BOM", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-16 be with bom" } },
    { "caption": "-" },
    { "caption": "Western (Windows 1252)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Western (Windows 1252)" } },
    { "caption": "Western (ISO 8859-1)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Western (ISO 8859-1)" } },
    { "caption": "Western (ISO 8859-3)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Western (ISO 8859-3)" } },
    { "caption": "Western (ISO 8859-15)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Western (ISO 8859-15)" } },
    { "caption": "Western (Mac Roman)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Western (Mac Roman)" } },
    { "caption": "DOS (CP 437)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "DOS (CP 437)" } },
    { "caption": "Arabic (Windows 1256)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Arabic (Windows 1256)" } },
    { "caption": "Arabic (ISO 8859-6)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Arabic (ISO 8859-6)" } },
    { "caption": "Baltic (Windows 1257)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Baltic (Windows 1257)" } },
    { "caption": "Baltic (ISO 8859-4)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Baltic (ISO 8859-4)" } },
    { "caption": "Celtic (ISO 8859-14)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Celtic (ISO 8859-14)" } },
    { "caption": "Central European (Windows 1250)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Central European (Windows 1250)" } },
    { "caption": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)" } },
    { "caption": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)" } },
    { "caption": "Cyrillic (Windows 866)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 866)" } },
    { "caption": "Cyrillic (ISO 8859-5)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (ISO 8859-5)" } },
    { "caption": "Cyrillic (KOI8-R)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (KOI8-R)" } },
    { "caption": "Cyrillic (KOI8-U)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Cyrillic (KOI8-U)" } },
    { "caption": "Estonian (ISO 8859-13)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Estonian (ISO 8859-13)" } },
    { "caption": "Greek (Windows 1253)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Greek (Windows 1253)" } },
    { "caption": "Greek (ISO 8859-7)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Greek (ISO 8859-7)" } },
    { "caption": "Hebrew (Windows 1255)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Hebrew (Windows 1255)" } },
    { "caption": "Hebrew (ISO 8859-8)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Hebrew (ISO 8859-8)" } },
    { "caption": "Nordic (ISO 8859-10)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Nordic (ISO 8859-10)" } },
    { "caption": "Romanian (ISO 8859-16)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Romanian (ISO 8859-16)" } },
    { "caption": "Turkish (Windows 1254)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Turkish (Windows 1254)" } },
    { "caption": "Turkish (ISO 8859-9)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Turkish (ISO 8859-9)" } },
    { "caption": "Vietnamese (Windows 1258)", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Vietnamese (Windows 1258)" } },
    { "caption": "-" },
    { "caption": "Hexadecimal", "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "Hexadecimal" } }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

For Sublime 3:

```
 1. Go to Packages directory (in my case it is /opt/sublime_text/Packages)
 3. Make a backup of Default.sublime-package
 2. In Midnight Commander open archive Default.sublime-package (it is
    simply a zip archive) by pressing Enter key
 4. Copy Main.sublime-menu and Encoding.sublime-menu to temp directory
 5. Edit copied files and remove unnecessary encodings
 6. Copy changed files back to Default.sublime-package archive (i.e.
    with archive management abilities of Midnight Commander)
 7. Restart Sublime 3
```

p.s. sorry for my English as of it is not my native language